# Show that two modules $V_A$, $V_B$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

Let $K$ be a field and define two matrices:
\begin{align*}
 A:= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\ 0&3\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } B:= \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\ 0&3\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
We then define a $K[X]$-module on $V=K^2$ such that
\begin{align*}
K[X]\times V \rightarrow V, \quad (P,v)\mapsto P(A)\cdot v
\end{align*}
where $P(A)\in K^{2\times 2}$ is achieved by plugging in matrix $A$ into polynomial $P$ and $P(A)\cdot v$ is therefore the matrix-vector-multiplication. We call this module $V_A$. $V_B$ can be constructed similarly.

I want to show that for $K=\mathbb{Q}$ the modules $V_A,V_B$ are isomorphic.

---

My attempt:

This is a lot like the similarity problems for matrices. So I calculated
$$S=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\ 0&2\end{pmatrix}$$
so that
$$B = S^{-1}AS$$

Can I then define following? $$\phi: V_B\rightarrow V_A, \quad P(B)v \mapsto S^{-1}P(A)Sv$$

I guess the rest is just showing that this is an module-isomorphism.

\begin{align*}
&1.\quad \phi(B(v_1+v_2)) = S^{-1}AS (v_1+v_2) = S^{-1}ASv_1+ S^{-1}ASv_2 = \phi(Bv_1)+\phi(Bv_2)\\
&2.\quad \phi(r\cdot Bv)=rS^{-1}ASv = r\cdot \phi(Bv)
\end{align*}
for $v,v_1,v_2\in V$

Surjective: Let $P(A)v\in V_A$ for any $P\in K[X], v\in V$. Then it's easy to find the corresponding $\phi(SP(B)S^{-1}v)=P(A)v$

Injective: Assume $P_1(A)v=P_2(A)v$. Then $SP_1(B)S^{-1}v = SP_2(B)S^{-1}v \Rightarrow P_1(B) = P_2(B) $

Is that correct? My prof asked me to be especially careful with the notation since Linear Algebra and Modules are kinda fused here. Any remarks?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As far as I can see you are mixing up things a little. I thought that $V_B$ and $V_A$ as are loosely speaking $K^2$ together with some "special" scalar multiplication where we take scalars in $K[X]$. So your map $\phi$ should be declared on elements of $K^2$. The point is that scalar multiplication is defined differently on those two $K[X]$-modules.

Comment: @nilsw I don't quite understand. $P(B) v, P(A) v\in V= K^2$ so I'm defining my map $\phi$ on $V$, don't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually one can define $\phi:V_B\to V_A$ by $\phi(v)=Sv$. This map is bijective and clearly satisfies $\phi(v_1+v_2)=\phi(v_1)+\phi(v_2)$.

We have to show now that $\phi(P(X)v)=P(X)\phi(v)$. But $$\phi(P(X)v)=\phi(P(B)v)=S(P(B)v)=(SP(B))v=(P(A)S)v=P(A)(Sv)=P(X)\phi(v).$$